# Oracle update throws timeout

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having a very simple oracle update:

```
update inv_li_pck_inst set mig_li_pck_inst_id = 9377 where id = 9384
```

Both records exist in the table inv_li_pck_inst: `id=9377` and `id=9384`

Record with `id=9377` is migration record.

Problem is that this very simple update query takes ages to run - and at the end throws timeout exception. What could possibly be wrong here? IDs in the table `inv_li_pck_inst` are unique.

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "TESTING_INV"."INV_LI_PCK_INST" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LI_PCK_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "WORKFLOW_ID" NUMBER, 
    "INSERTED" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INSERTED_BY" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UPDATED" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "DELETED" DATE, 
    "DELETED_BY" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "MIG_LI_PCK_INST_ID" NUMBER, 
    "STATUS_ID" NUMBER, 
    "WFI_ID" NUMBER, 
    "TOF_WFI_ID" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_INV_LI_PCK_INST" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TESTING_INV_DATA"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_LPI_WORKFLOW" FOREIGN KEY ("WORKFLOW_ID")
      REFERENCES "TESTING_INV"."WORKFLOW" ("WORKFLOW_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_LIPI_STATUS" FOREIGN KEY ("STATUS_ID")
      REFERENCES "TESTING_INV"."INV_LI_PCK_INST_STATUS" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_LIPI_MIG_PCK_INST" FOREIGN KEY ("MIG_LI_PCK_INST_ID")
      REFERENCES "TESTING_INV"."INV_LI_PCK_INST" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_LI_PCK_INST_WFI" FOREIGN KEY ("WFI_ID")
      REFERENCES "TESTING_INV"."WFI" ("WFI_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_INV_LI_PCK_INST5" FOREIGN KEY ("TOF_WFI_ID")
      REFERENCES "TESTING_INV"."WFI" ("WFI_ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_LPI_LI_PCK" FOREIGN KEY ("LI_PCK_ID")
      REFERENCES "TESTING_INV"."INV_LI_PCK" ("ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TESTING_INV_DATA" ;

  CREATE INDEX "TESTING_INV"."IDX_LI_PCK_INST_WFI" ON "TESTING_INV"."INV_LI_PCK_INST" ("WFI_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TESTING_INV_DATA" ;

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "TESTING_INV"."UN_LI_PCK_INST" ON "TESTING_INV"."INV_LI_PCK_INST" (NVL2("DELETED","ID",NULL), "WORKFLOW_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TESTING_INV_DATA" ;

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "TESTING_INV"."TRG_INV_LI_PCK_INST" 
before insert on INV_LI_PCK_INST
for each row
begin
  select SEQ_INV_LI_PCK_INST.nextval into :new.ID from dual;
end;


/
ALTER TRIGGER "TESTING_INV"."TRG_INV_LI_PCK_INST" ENABLE;
```

Comment: Do you have up to date statistics for that table? What does the explain plan look like?

Comment: Is there potentially another session that has not committed that is locking the table or row?

Comment: @EJEgyed - how to check this?

Comment: The will not fit into a comment here, but you can try the queries found on this page: https://www.toolbox.com/tech/oracle/question/how-to-check-uncommitted-transaction-in-oracle-database-120712/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probable scenario is that there is *an other* migration session (or more of them) and it blocks your session.

Simple setup

```
create table testing
(ID NUMBER primary key,
 MIG_ID NUMBER );

alter table testing add (
constraint mig foreign key(MIG_ID) references testing(id));

insert into testing (id, mig_id) values(9384, null);
insert into testing (id, mig_id) values(9377, null);
 
commit;
```

If you now performs the `UPDATE` is goes perfectly smooth:

```
update testing set mig_id = 9377 where id = 9384;
```

But if you before the update performs a `delete` of the migrated `ID` **form an other session and do not commit it**, your update will "hang" forever.

```
-- perform from other session and do not commit
delete from testing where id = 9377;
```

Why, because if the update would be done and the delete session would be commited - the referential integrity will be violeted. The `UPDATE` must *wait* until the deleted is commited or rollbacked to see if the reference ID is there or not.

How to dignose?

Simple check the `v$session` (or GV of RAC) and see the *blocking_status* and *event*

```
select SID, SERIAL#,STATUS,SQL_ID, BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS, BLOCKING_SESSION,EVENT 
from v$session 
where USERNAME = your_user
```

You will see (most probably) your session with `BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS = VALID` and
`EVENT = enq: TX - row lock contention`. In BLOCKING_SESSION you can find the session ID of your *interacting session*.

The `SQL_ID` will tell you what the other session is doing.